# Array in a program

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

So, first I like to state that I'm very new to Python, so this probably will be an easy question. I'm exercising my programming skills and am trying to write a simple program. It goes like this:

```
def cal(alpha, k):
    sqrt = np.zeros(len(alpha))
    for i in range(len(alpha)):
        sqrt[i] = np.sqrt(alpha[i])*k
        return sqrt
```

Which, for a certain `alpha` and `k`, should give me an array `sqrt[]`. For example, if `alpha = [1,4,9]` and `k = 3`, the answer should be `[3,6,9]`. However, when executed in Python, it gives `[3,0,0]`.

My question is: why? I know I can get what I want if I simply put

```
 def cal(alpha, k):
     sqrt = np.zeros(len(alpha))
     sqrt= np.sqrt(alpha)*k
     return sqrt
```

but I want to know where my mistake in reasoning is.

Thanks!

Comment: Take care of your indentation. Just know that `return` statement always stops a function execution. Because your return is on the same level than your loop, in fact you'll loop only once and then returns your array after you change only the first value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indentation is important in Python. As soon as your function reaches the `return` statement, it will stop and return an object.

In your `for` loop, `return` is met at the end of the first iteration but before the start of the second, which is why you find only the first value filled in `[3, 0, 0]`.

Therefore, simply unindent the last line. This will ensure `return` is only processed after your `for` loop is completed:

```
import numpy as np

def cal(alpha, k):
    sqrt = np.zeros(len(alpha))
    for i in range(len(alpha)):
        sqrt[i] = np.sqrt(alpha[i])*k
    return sqrt

cal([1, 4, 9], 3)

# array([ 3.,  6.,  9.])
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer that `jpp` provided, your second block of code

```
def cal(alpha, k):
  sqrt = np.zeros(len(alpha))
  sqrt= np.sqrt(alpha)*k
  return sqrt
```

works due to nifty little trick called [numpy boardcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Essentially, when any **numpy** array is multiplied by a scaler (in your case `k`), the effect is as you'd intuitively expect: each individual value in the array is multiplied. There are a few more use-cases explained in the official numpy broadcasting documentation.